# How to solve this problem, after your code goes here

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function displayNewsPanel() {

    console.log('here')

    // Create a variable named 'newsItems' that is a handle to the element with the ID of 'newsPanel'

    const newsItems = document.querySelector('#newsPanel')

    // This is the array of news that you are to use. Note that it is an array of arrays.

    const news =

        [

            ['May 22, 2018', 'Really Big News', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum iusto provident sit vero, eius fugiat autem laboriosam, molestiae, quidem incidunt ducimus reiciendis fugit illo quisquam. Autem, veniam voluptas officia incidunt.', 'http://clark.edu'],

            ['May 30, 2018', 'OK News', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum iusto provident sit vero, eius fugiat autem laboriosam, molestiae, quidem incidunt ducimus reiciendis fugit illo quisquam. Autem, veniam voluptas officia incidunt.', 'http://clark.edu'],

            ['June 14, 2018', 'GREAT NEWS!', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum iusto provident sit vero, eius fugiat autem laboriosam, molestiae, quidem incidunt ducimus reiciendis fugit illo quisquam. Autem, veniam voluptas officia incidunt.', 'http://clark.edu'],

            ['July 2, 2018', 'Welcome Back', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum iusto provident sit vero, eius fugiat autem laboriosam, molestiae, quidem incidunt ducimus reiciendis fugit illo quisquam. Autem, veniam voluptas officia incidunt.', 'http://clark.edu']

        ]

    // Use this variable to build the output string that you will then use for the news

    let output = ''

    // Loop through the news array of arrays. No need for nested loops.

    for (let i = 0; i < news.length; i++) {

        // Generate the HTML code that you will need to build the news string

     // Your code goes here

     // Add the output to the newsItem element

newsItems.innerHTML = output
```

This is javascript. I'm getting stuck at generate the HTML code that you will need to build the news string, I need `output = output + new[I][0]`

It should display by format like this:

> name-day,
>
> Lorem ipsum color ...,
>
> Linked. (the hyperlink)

Comment: What code have you already written to answer the question? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Comment: Your question is not really clear. Would you like to build the HTML or String for output? - (mày viết câu hỏi dở quá :| đọc chả hiểu gì cả... cuối cùng muốn tìm mã html hay là string ra...)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create a format for how you are going to layout the elements from the array like, putting the date in a paragraph tag and so on.

Later you can create a html string format of the same version for eg. `<p>Date, Title, Lorem Ipsum</p> <a href='someusefullink.com'>Sample Link</a>` and then appending the same to your output string and setting the innerHTML of the requested element. The code for the above should look like this:

```
    let output = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < news.length; i++) {
        output += `<p>${news[i][0]}, ${news[i][1]} ${news[i][2]}</p> <a href='${news[i][3]}'>${news[i][3]}</a>`; 
    }
    newsItems.innerHTML = output;
```

Answer (score 0):

loop for must written like this

```
for (let i = 0; i < news.length; i++) {
  output += `${news[i][0]} - ${news[i][1]} - ${news[i][3]}`;
}
```